# Removing "other bookmarks" from the Firefox bookmarks manager?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, firefox-profile, firefox-developer-tools

I don't know what this folder is for, and I don't know why Firefox forced this folder for everyone.  But for me It is always empty because I never use it.  I want to go a step further and permanently hide it from this drop down menu and the bookmarks manager.  It's stupid and it really needs to go.

[image: Other bookmarks]

Answer (score 2):

The **Other Bookmarks** folder can be used to store additional bookmarks that will be displayed at the end of the Bookmarks toolbar.

> [image: Other Bookmarks]

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-other-bookmarks-folder-from-bookmarks-toolbar

## Hide via userChrome.css

To hide it in the Bookmarks menu, you can use [userChrome.css](https://www.userchrome.org/). Add this code to your userChrome.css file and restart Firefox:

```
#menu_unsortedBookmarks {
    display: none !important;
}

#BMB_unsortedBookmarks {
    display: none !important;
}
```

[image: Hidden]

Comment: Thanks for your help but sadly it didnt do anything.  toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets is set to true in about config btw (dunno why its disabled by default but this is Mozilla after all).

https://imgur.com/llgA7qx

Comment: @Matt I found what might be causing the difference. I'm using bookmarks from the menu bar but you are using the specific [Bookmarks menu](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarks-firefox#w_bookmarks-menu-button-on-the-toolbar). I swapped to that and found it's using a different id so I have added that one to the `userChrome.css`. Hope it works!

Comment: You can inspect the underlying elements of Firefox's base UI (also known as chrome but not the browser) using the [Browser Toolbox](https://superuser.com/questions/1608096/how-to-inspect-firefoxs-ui). Then you just find the element you want to hide or modify, and add that to userChrome.css.

Comment: Does it work for thunderbird also?  There are some elements I wish to hide on there as well.  A lot actually.  Thanks for your help.  You did much more than anyone at the mozilla forum could.

Comment: It looks like Thunderbird also supports use of a custom userChrome.css, just from a brief search. I haven't used Thunderbird before so I'm not sure if it has the same Browser Toolbox or how you would find the elements though.

Comment: How do you inspect an element for menus that require a mouse click to open?  As soon as I click the inspect element button, the bookmarks toolbar menu hides.  Same with an element within the search panel that requires the URL bar to be clicked to open.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get the `userChrome.css` method in [@MC10's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1764992/1802107) to successfully hide menu items on macOS, but it's possible to via an [AutoConfig file](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig).

```javascript
// -*- mode: javascript; -*- vim: set ft=javascript:
// See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig
"use strict";

(() => {
  if (Services.appinfo.inSafeMode) {
    return;
  }

  const addressPattern = new RegExp(
    "^(chrome:(?!//(global/content/commonDialog)\\.xhtml)|about:(?!blank))"
  );

  Services.obs.addObserver(subject => {
    subject.addEventListener(
      "DOMContentLoaded",
      event => {
        const document = event.originalTarget;
        const window = document.defaultView;
        if (!addressPattern.test(window.location.href)) {
          return;
        }

        const hiddenMenuItems = [
          "bookmarksToolbarFolderMenu",
          "menu_unsortedBookmarks",
          "bookmarksMenuItemsSeparator"
        ];
        for (const id of hiddenMenuItems) {
          const element = document.getElementById(id);
          if (element) {
            element.hidden = true;
          }
        }
      },
      { once: true }
    );
  }, "chrome-document-global-created");
})();
```

The above example also hides the bookmarks toolbar menu item and separator. To only hide the "Other Bookmarks" folder, just use `menu_unsortedBookmarks`.

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1785959/1802107) for additional context and installation instructions.

The browser DOM can be shown by using the [Browser Toolbox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_toolbox/index.html) or navigating to:

```
view-source:chrome://browser/content/browser.xhtml
```

To hide "Other Bookmarks" from the "Add bookmark" panel, add this to `userChrome.css`:

```css
#editBMPanel_unfiledRootItem {
    display: none;
}
```

Additional instructions for enabling `userChrome.css` are [available here](https://old.reddit.com/r/firefox/wiki/userchrome).

**Note:** This will not remove the "Other Bookmarks" folder from the "Manage Bookmarks" library window, or the bookmarks sidebar.